# Holomorphic differential on the algebraic curve $y^3=(x^2+1)^2(x^3-1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to find three holomorphic differential non-constant on the algebraic curve $y^3=(x^2+1)^2(x^3-1)$ in order to obtain a basis for $\mathcal{L}(K)$. I have found the canonical divisor
$$div\left(\frac{z^2}{3y^2}dx\right)=10 [0:1:0]-2[i:0:1]-2[-i:0:1]$$
I'm quite sure that $1,\frac{x^2+z^2}{y^2},\frac{z}{y}\in\mathcal{L}(K)$, I've showed $\frac{(x^2+z^2)(x-iz)}{y^2z}\in\mathcal{L}(K)$ but it is not useful in order to find the equations of the canonical model. Any ideas?